# Позиционарование элемента. Центрирование в доступной области

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как в имеющемся [примере](http://jsfiddle.net/kJM6T/3/) сделать чтобы блок с текстом по вертикали всегда выравнивался по центру, не зависимо от размеров картинки (может быть разной)?

```css
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width:250px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1%
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://photomotion.ru/uploads/users/1/1226568467.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div>
        <p>Какой-то текст. Заголовок</p>
        <p>Какой-то текст</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img src="http://photomotion.ru/uploads/users/1/1226568530.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div>
        <p>Какой-то текст. Заголовок</p>
        <p>Какой-то текст</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: img
text
img{visibility:hidden}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?  http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/Z6NnQ/

```
<table class="tbl">
   <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="center">
          <img src="http://photomotion.ru/uploads/users/1/1226568467.jpg" alt="img"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="center">
          <p>Какой-то текст. Заголовок</p>
          <p>Какой-то текст</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: всегда недооцениваю табличную верстку, пора уже перестать их сравнивать как лучше и хуже...

Answer (score 1):

**[Посмотреть решение](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/8249q/4/embedded/result/)**

**html**

```
<div class="box">
    <img class="logo" src="http://photomotion.ru/uploads/users/1/1226568467.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Какой-то текст. Заголовок</p>
            <p>Какой-то текст</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.box {        
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 0 0 1%;
    min-width:250px;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {        
    display: table-row;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.text-wrapper {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
.text {        
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```